# Ubuntu Desktop 21.10 64bit fails to boot setup screen on RPi 4B+

Tags: boot, system-installation, screen, raspberrypi, boot-repair

Just wanna know as I had the same problem for my RPi 4B+. It bootup, but then it won't show anything or just does not show any setup screen after turning on the device aka no display... Can anyone help to solve this issue??

Comment: Edit your question and describe all steps needed to reproduce the problem. As you have currently written this question, it's not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: I mean like it boots to the loading screen for ubuntu but then it went blank again. The process I did was by only reflashing my micro SD card but that does not work,then I download the img file directly from ubuntu.com but tht does not work also after I tried to reflash the micro sd card in smaller speed but tht does not work and so on... I found many online guide that were not useful at all into helping me solve this situation...